# How to set Navigation back button icon in all view controller like globally?

Tags: ios

I can perform operation to set navigation back button icon on all the views commonly. For example if I put code in App Delegate method then it's used for all the controllers.

Comment: i have also done this but not in Delegate method,i have create code for each controller..... please refer below link Thank You. -Opal
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30679152/4944302

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is The final Answer which i have used in my current App hope it will useful..

in view DidLoad method..

```
UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
[leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(left_menu_click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem;
```

add this method for navigate popViewController..

```
-(IBAction)left_menu_click:(id)sender{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thank you so much.. its really great i appreciate your answer

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131305/srimca-2012-2015. pls follow this link

Comment: But this is not global

Answer (score 1):

You may try below appearance with correct image for back button throughout app.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_bg"]
                                                      forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: its works but whenever application runs at time with back image it also returns Back Label which are inbuilt.
So what are the alternative solution to prevent this issue.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate` class :

```
// Following line is for tint color that is optional, You can add if you wants to change color of back button
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

If you want change background images then

```
// Change the appearance of back button
    UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_back"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 6)];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: hey...code is execute well but the thing is that whenever application runs it display default name BACK in background of whatever image we've set...how to prevent this issue ? Thank You.

Comment: [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-500.f, 0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Answer (score 1):

You may try custom button like this:

```
+ (UIBarButtonItem *)backButtonForTarget:(id)target
{
UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn addTarget:target action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 44)];
[btn setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(11, -10, 8, 35)];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topbar_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *barbtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
return barbtnItem;
}
```

add this button as leftBarButtonItem

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [UtilityClass backButtonForTarget:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found a solution using appearance()

**Swift**

```
    let backImage = UIImage(named: "back")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = backImage
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:
        UIColor.white], for: .normal)
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.green
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify `UINavigationBar` like:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
appearance.backIndicatorImage = image
appearance.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = image
```

If you want to remove default title, you add:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

to view controller that pushes to the navigation controller.

You can find more on [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar#3022835)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  let backImage = UIImage(named: "icon")
  let backImageUIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -4, left: -8, bottom: -2, right: 8)
  let backImageWithAlignmentRectInsets = backImage?.withAlignmentRectInsets(backImageUIEdgeInsets)
  appearance.setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(-1.0, for: .default)
  appearance.setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backImageWithAlignmentRectInsets,
                                          for: .normal,
                                          barMetrics: .default)
  appearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear],
                                    for: .normal)
  appearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear],
                                    for: .highlighted)
```